# How to activate battery conservation mode, linix mint 20.1, Lenovo Legion7i

Tags: linux-mint, battery

I've found a number of posts across forums and on archwiki that reference the following solution for this laptop model

```
echo 1 > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004\:00/conservation_mode
```

This should essentially activate conservation mode for the machine (note: From what I can find the Legion7i classes itself as an ideapad, rather than a thinkpad)

**My issue:** I can not get the file to shift from 0 to 1.

**Tried:**
The above command as su in terminal AND changing permissions to ensure rw access, and editing via text editor. In every instance when I check the output from the file, its 0.

**Note:** I dual boot win10. For a time, when setting battery conservation mode on in win10, it would hold for when I booted in to linux. Now, regardless of what OS I boot into, the system seems to revert back to conservation mode off every time. Ive found no relevant settings to battery power/management in the BIOS (ver 4.05).

Im no advanced user, so any info would be great. even if the answer is "cant be done, your machine wont allow it", thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Head to TLP:

https://linrunner.de/tlp/

"TLP is a feature-rich command line utility for Linux, saving laptop battery power without the need to delve deeper into technical details.

TLP’s default settings are already optimized for battery life, so you may just install and forget it. Nevertheless TLP is highly customizable to fulfil your specific requirements.  [...]"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave TLP a go, but its not compatible with my machine so although I can run it and put the settings in, it doesnt take hold. I get the feeling I'm limited by the BIOS or kernel

Comment: Hardware is effectively the limiting factor, high power economy pc have the soft and hard designed together.